# D365 Opportunity notes attachments using Postman

Tags: annotations, postman, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-sales

I need help with my `JSON` construct. I am attempting to attach the below base64 string and to bind an existing Opportunity in D365 - using postman

WebApi **Request** :

POST : https://Mydomainurl.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/annotations

```
{
  "subject": "Test From Web API",
  "filename": "encoded oppjs.txt",
  "opportunity@odata.bind ":"/opportunity(0cff802f-23e1-40b3-aebc-b36b6d8d2e68)",
  "documentbody" : "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"

}
```

**Response** :
501 Bad Request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this json on :
`POST` : `https://Mydomainurl.api.crm8.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/annotations`
and let me know, you had a couple of things wrong note the odata.bind and how this binds to the opportunity in D365 you want to link too, that and you had some spacing issues in the pasted example as well:

```
{
    "subject": "Test From Web API", 
    "filename": "encoded oppjs.txt", 
    "isdocument" : true,
    "objectid_opportunity@odata.bind": "opportunities(0cff802f-23e1-40b3-aebc-b36b6d8d2e68)", 
"documentbody":"DQp2YXIgdzMgPSB7fTsNCnczLmhpZGUgPSBmdW5jdGlvbiAoc2VsKSB7DQogIHczLmhpZGVFbGVt ZW50cyh3My5nZXRFbGVtZW50cyhzZWwpKTsNCn07DQp3My5oaWRlRWxlbWVudHMgPSBmdW5jdGlv biAoZWxlbWVudHMpIHsNCiAgdmFyIGksIGwgPSBlbGVtZW50cy5sZW5ndGg7DQogIGZvciAoaSA9IDA7IGkgPCBsOyBpKyspIHsNCiAgICB3My5oaWRlRWxlbWVudChlbGVtZW50c1tpXSk7DQogIH0N Cn07DQp3My5oaWRlRWxlbWVudCA9IGZ1bmN0aW9uIChlbGVtZW50KSB7DQogIHczLnN0eWxlRWxlbWVudChlbGVtZW50LCAiZGlzcGxheSIsICJub25lIik7DQp9Ow0KdzMuc2hvdyA9IGZ1bmN0aW9u IChzZWwsIGEpIHsNCiAgdmFyIGVsZW1lbnRzID0gdzMuZ2V0RWxlbWVudHMoc2VsKTsNCiAgaWYgKGEpIHt3My5oaWRlRWxlbWVudHMoZWxlbWVudHMpO30NCiAgdzMuc2hvd0VsZW1lbnRzKGVsZW1l bnRzKTsNCn07DQp3My5zaG93RWxlbWVudHMgPSBmdW5jdGlvbiAoZWxlbWVudHMpIHsNCiAgdmFyIGksIGwgPSBlbGVtZW50cy5sZW5ndGg7DQogIGZvciAoaSA9IDA7IGkgPCBsOyBpKyspIHsNCiAg ICB3My5zaG93RWxlbWVudChlbGVtZW50c1tpXSk7DQogIH0NCn07DQp3My5zaG93RWxlbWVudCA9IGZ1bmN0aW9uIChlbGVtZW50KSB7DQogIHczLnN0eWxlRWxlbWVudChlbGVtZW50LCAiZGlzcGxh" 
}
```

Comment: Yes It Shows 201 created , Could you please tell me how to get that file in opportunity in D365

Comment: Try using url with your oppid https://yourorg.crm8.dynamics.com/main.aspx?pagetype=entityrecord&etn=opportunity&id=0cff802f-23e1-40b3-aebc-b36b6d8d2e68 to open that opportunity it should have a note with an attachment